# Js task with array and sum

Tags: javascript

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function sum() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
}
```

How to use this function sum to count array sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you need to return a value from your `sum` function:

```
function sum() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var result = sum.apply(null, list);
```

Note however, this whole method can be replaced with a call to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (introduced in ES5):

```
var result = list.reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y; });
```